# ggplot2: missing legend and how to add?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to plot a bar and line chart from a dataframe. Code below,

```
library("ggplot2")

numb <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
mydist <- c(53.846154,15.384615,15.384615,7.692308,7.692308,0,0,0,0)
basedist <- c(30.103,17.609126,12.493874,9.691001,7.918125,6.694679,5.799195,5.115252,4.575749)
df <- data.frame(numb, mydist, basedist)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=numb)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y=mydist), colour="green", fill="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y=basedist,group=1, colour="base distribution")) +  
  geom_point(aes(y=basedist), colour="red") +
  ggtitle("My Chart") +
  labs(x="numb", y="percentage") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, colour ="#666666")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=10, color="#666666")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0, color="#666666")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size = 16, face='bold'))
```

Result is not I wanted because there is no legend for the bars

[image]

I reproduced the chart I need with the same data set in Excel below,
[image]

What do I need to change in my code to get the chart I need?

Thanks,
Lobbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing much of the original code, you only need to put your `fill` into `aes` mapping, then add the `scale` to set the colour `values` and `labels`:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=numb)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y=mydist, fill="green"), colour="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y=basedist,group=1, colour="base distribution")) +  
  geom_point(aes(y=basedist), colour="red") +
  ggtitle("My Chart") +
  labs(x="numb", y="percentage") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "green", labels = "my distribution") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, colour ="#666666")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=10, color="#666666")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0, color="#666666")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size = 16, face='bold'))
```

[image]

Comment: @zyurnaidi- nice example - you beat me to it :-)

Comment: @zyumaidi, thank you!  I understand where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a brief example. In general, I would recommend you reformat ggplot() assignment to make debugging easier. i.e. `gp <- gp +`

```
gp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=numb))
gp <- gp + geom_bar( aes(y = mydist, fill = "green"), stat="identity", color="green")
gp <- gp + geom_line( aes( y = basedist, group = 1, colour = "base distribution"))
gp <- gp + scale_fill_manual(values = "green", labels = "my distribution")
gp <- gp + geom_point(aes(y=basedist), colour="red") 
gp <- gp + ggtitle("My Chart") 
gp <- gp + labs(x="numb", y="percentage") 
gp <- gp + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")) 
gp <- gp + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) 
gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, colour ="#666666"))
gp <- gp + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=10, color="#666666"))
gp <- gp + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", hjust=0, color="#666666"))
gp <- gp + theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12)) 
gp <- gp + theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size = 16, face='bold'))
gp <- gp + theme(legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title=element_blank(), legend.box  ="vertical")
gp
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer too.  If only I can accept 2 answers and I will take your recommendation going forward.  thanks again.

Comment: Lobbie - no problem. Happy to help, the points are an aside. Take care.